# Is it possible to configure MariaDB encryption to use more resources?

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I have enabled [MariaDB data-at-rest encryption](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/data-at-rest-encryption-overview/) using the [file key management plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/). I want to test performance, so I've done it on a snapshot database where I previously copied all of the data from our production database, there is nothing else running on this database.

Here's the config values I set up:

```
[mariadb]
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
encrypt_binlog = ON
encrypt_tmp_disk_tables = ON
encrypt_tmp_files = ON

innodb_encrypt_tables = FORCE
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age=1
innodb_encryption_threads = 32
innodb_tablespaces_encryption
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops = 40000
```

I'm using the following query to track encryption progress ([found here from MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-encryption-overview/#finding-encrypted-tables)):

```sql
SELECT te.SPACE, te.NAME, te.ENCRYPTION_SCHEME, te.ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING
FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION te
ORDER BY te.ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING, te.NAME;
```

I have a fairly powerful database server with the storage array being a RAID 6 setup of 8 SSDs, 256GB of memory, and an AMD EPYC 73F3 (and again, nothing else running on the server to take up resources, and no one running any queries or changing data as this is a copy of the database).

My MariaDB version is:

```
10.10.3-MariaDB-1:10.10.3+maria~deb11-log
```

The above query shows only 3 tables at a time being encrypted, and even very very small tables (in one particular case, a table with only a single row) seemingly can take many hours to finish encrypting.

Using `htop` and `iotop` I can see little to no resources are being used at all. No CPU usage, and no disk IO usage.

How can I tell the MariaDB server to fully encrypt the whole database at full speed? I want it to go as fast as the hardware will allow it, reading every table, encrypting it, and writing it back. I don't know if it's trying to preserve performance to not overload a live system, but at this rate it will take months for the full database to be encrypted.

I've tried adjusting the `innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age` and `innodb_encryption_rotation_iops` variables, but neither change anything. The MariaDB documentation give an example of `1024` for `innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age`, so that's what I tried first. I found another exmaple which showed a value of `1`, but it didn't change anything.

I found [this article](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/moving-a-mariadb-database-to-encrypted-and-unencrypted-states/), which suggests using the value of `40000` for `innodb_encryption_rotation_iops`. I tried that value, as well as values up to `120000` and as low as `2000` and found no difference with any of them.

---

Logs:

```
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.10.3-MariaDB-1:10.10.3+maria~deb11-log source revision cc8b9bcee3ce88bc52147948f96765cd5009b88a as process 518472
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_socket.so' (errno: 0, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [ERROR] Couldn't load plugins from 'auth_socket.so'.
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2023-03-24 20:03:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 200.000GiB, chunk size = 3.125GiB
2023-03-24 20:03:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-24 20:03:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=4096 bytes)
2023-03-24 20:03:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=54613025613622
2023-03-24 20:03:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 7157836 pages from redo log.
2023-03-24 20:03:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 6853690 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:03:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 6451674 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:03:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 6049299 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:04:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 5644781 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:04:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 5242320 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:04:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 4840063 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:04:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 4437667 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:05:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 4037295 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:05:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 3633319 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:05:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 3229202 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:05:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 2869239 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:06:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 1969196 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:06:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 974294 pages from log
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last binlog file '/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.015800', position 11407367
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 54613180673322; transaction id 137255357282
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #1 encryption thread id 139485790574336 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /data/mariadb/ib_buffer_pool
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #2 encryption thread id 139485304059648 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #3 encryption thread id 139485295666944 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #4 encryption thread id 139485287274240 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #5 encryption thread id 139485278881536 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #6 encryption thread id 139485270488832 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #7 encryption thread id 139485262096128 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #8 encryption thread id 139485253703424 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #9 encryption thread id 139485245310720 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #10 encryption thread id 139485236918016 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #11 encryption thread id 139485228525312 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #12 encryption thread id 139485220132608 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #13 encryption thread id 139485211739904 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #14 encryption thread id 139485203347200 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #15 encryption thread id 139485194954496 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #16 encryption thread id 139485186561792 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #17 encryption thread id 139485178169088 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #18 encryption thread id 139485169776384 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #19 encryption thread id 139485161383680 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #20 encryption thread id 139485152990976 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #21 encryption thread id 139485144598272 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #22 encryption thread id 139485136205568 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #23 encryption thread id 139485127812864 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #24 encryption thread id 139485119420160 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #25 encryption thread id 139485111027456 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #26 encryption thread id 139485102634752 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #27 encryption thread id 139485094242048 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #28 encryption thread id 139485085849344 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #29 encryption thread id 139485077456640 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #30 encryption thread id 139485069063936 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #31 encryption thread id 139485060671232 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #32 encryption thread id 139485052278528 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
230324 20:06:33 server_audit: MariaDB Audit Plugin version 1.4.14 STARTED.
230324 20:06:33 server_audit: Query cache is enabled with the TABLE events. Some table reads can be veiled.2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Warning] 'innodb-buffer-pool-instances' was removed. It does nothing now and exists only for compatibility with old my.cnf files.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Using encryption key id 1 for temporary files
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /data/binlogs/mysql-bin
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Starting table crash recovery...
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Crash table recovery finished.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-03-24 20:06:33 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.10.3-MariaDB-1:10.10.3+maria~deb11-log'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-03-24 20:06:33 4 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-03-24 20:06:33 5 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-03-24 20:07:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230324 20:07:01
2023-03-24 20:08:13 6 [Warning] IP address '192.168.178.71' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2023-03-24 21:35:31 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2023-03-24 21:35:31 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 1 events
2023-03-24 21:35:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
--------------- The previous line is where it sat frozen for a long time after stopping with systemd ---------------
--------------- After killing mariadb with SIGKILL, the log continues ---------------
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.10.3-MariaDB-1:10.10.3+maria~deb11-log source revision cc8b9bcee3ce88bc52147948f96765cd5009b88a as process 521104
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_socket.so' (errno: 0, cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [ERROR] Couldn't load plugins from 'auth_socket.so'.
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2023-03-24 22:12:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 200.000GiB, chunk size = 3.125GiB
2023-03-24 22:12:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-24 22:12:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=4096 bytes)
2023-03-24 22:12:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=54613025613622
2023-03-24 22:12:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=377571324, page number=3] with future log sequence number 54613218732323
2023-03-24 22:12:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 8797001 pages from redo log.
2023-03-24 22:12:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 8521740 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:12:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 8119838 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:12:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 7718800 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 7315215 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 6913326 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:13:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 6511373 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:13:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 6109282 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:14:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 5709102 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:14:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 5305434 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 4900967 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:14:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 4512167 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:15:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 3679339 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 2663469 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:15:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 1639104 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:15:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 629774 pages from log
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last binlog file '/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.015800', position 11407367
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 54613218731849; transaction id 137255357282
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #1 encryption thread id 139684080514816 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #2 encryption thread id 139683241637632 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #3 encryption thread id 139684197947136 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /data/mariadb/ib_buffer_pool
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #4 encryption thread id 139684684494592 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #5 encryption thread id 139686693959424 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #6 encryption thread id 139686685566720 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #7 encryption thread id 139686668781312 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #8 encryption thread id 139686660388608 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #9 encryption thread id 139686651995904 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #10 encryption thread id 139684676101888 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #11 encryption thread id 139684642531072 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #12 encryption thread id 139684634138368 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #13 encryption thread id 139684214732544 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #14 encryption thread id 139684164376320 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #15 encryption thread id 139684072122112 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #16 encryption thread id 139684055336704 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #17 encryption thread id 139684046944000 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #18 encryption thread id 139684030158592 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #19 encryption thread id 139683275208448 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #20 encryption thread id 139683266815744 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #21 encryption thread id 139683258423040 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #22 encryption thread id 139683250030336 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #23 encryption thread id 139683233244928 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #24 encryption thread id 139682058856192 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #25 encryption thread id 139682050463488 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #26 encryption thread id 139682042070784 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #27 encryption thread id 139682033678080 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #28 encryption thread id 139682025285376 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #29 encryption thread id 139682016892672 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #30 encryption thread id 139681597486848 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #31 encryption thread id 139681589094144 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #32 encryption thread id 139681580701440 total threads 32.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
230324 22:15:57 server_audit: MariaDB Audit Plugin version 1.4.14 STARTED.
230324 22:15:57 server_audit: Query cache is enabled with the TABLE events. Some table reads can be veiled.2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Warning] 'innodb-buffer-pool-instances' was removed. It does nothing now and exists only for compatibility with old my.cnf files.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Using encryption key id 1 for temporary files
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /data/binlogs/mysql-bin
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Starting table crash recovery...
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Crash table recovery finished.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-03-24 22:15:57 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.10.3-MariaDB-1:10.10.3+maria~deb11-log'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-03-24 22:15:58 4 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-03-24 22:15:58 5 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2023-03-24 22:16:10 6 [Warning] IP address '192.168.178.71' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: sounds suspicious, please write a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Comment: Alright, I'll do that if I don't make any other progress. I think there might be some other issue as the server also blocks forever when shutting down now, not sure what is wrong. Nothing appears out of place in the logs. I wonder if there's a lock being held somewhere or a handle that needs to be released - not sure. I'll also try upgrading the MariaDB server as well.

Comment: Actually, the log shows
```
InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
```
As the last entry, which is where it seems to be getting stuck on shutting down. I wonder if the two problems are related.

Comment: Include full logs in your question.

Comment: I've edited the question to contain the logs.